# Customize QScrollBar intersection using stylesheet Qt

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt4

I’ve already customize my horizontal and vertical scrollbars using a stylesheet no problem.
But there still an annoying tiny area which remains blank :

The intersection of an horizontal and vertical bar. A small rectangle.

How could I change its color ? (Using stylesheets )

Thank you !

Qt 4.7.1 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Ps: Even on the Qt stylesheet example it’s still white.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I realise this is an old question, but I found a better solution.

```
QAbstractScrollArea::corner {
    background: somecolor;
}
```

Or, to hide it, use:

```
background: transparent;
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, the scroll area corner will be painted with the Window palette. Unfortunately, you cannot change the Window palette using only stylesheets. However, what you can do is create a dummy widget and set it to be displayed in the corner area with `QAbstractScrollArea::setCornerWidget(QWidget *widget)`, and then use the stylesheet to change the color of *that* widget.

Comment: Thank you, hard to find this one.
Well the problem now is that cornerWidget is always displayed. I'd like to show it only when there is an intersection.
Any idea ?

Comment: cornerWidget->setVisible(scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->isVisible() && scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->isVisible());

Comment: It was not working, I actually reimplemented resizeEvent and set a corner widget only when the bar was visible. Else delete it. Thanks for the tip.